# Lumen How to Authenticate User and Client

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth-2.0, lumen, laravel-passport

I have built an API using lumen, but struggling with authentication. Examples online seem to either deal with client authentication (a web app connecting to the API with a client ID and secret returning an access [lumen client auth](https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/lumen-passport)) or user authentication (taking the email address and password of a user and providing an access token [lumen user auth](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)).

Does anyone have details on how to implement both into one Lumen API so that you can allow both user and client authentication? Ideally email address and password for user auth then id and secret for client auth.

Comment: https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/jwt-authentication-for-lumen-5-6-2376fd38d454 I suggest you use jwt, and link above has full guide to it, have fun

Comment: Thank you Edin, I will take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Used alternative https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/jwt-authentication-for-lumen-5-6-2376fd38d454 as recommended by fellow stackoverflower.